# Android BLE simultaneous connections from several apps to the same BLE device

Tags: android, bluetooth-lowenergy

I'm a new at BLE. So, I'm confused with situation where it's supposed to have Android phone where several apps work in background and use BLE for scanning of others BLE devices. 
Is it possible to establish simultaneous connections from my apps to the same BLE (peripheral) device? If is not possible how will such case be resolved? What app will get access to BLE device the first?

Answer (score 0):

No it is not possible. A Bluetooth LE device can only make one connection at a time.

If you need a connection shared between you apps, you can create a service to handle that connection and send data to and from your apps using a broadcast.